# iMac Late 2009 Target Display Mode to GTX 1080

Tags: macos, display, imac, displayport, target-disk-mode

I have the requisite model iMac -Late 2009 iMac, and a brand new PC build employing AMD Threadripper and a GTX1080. I would like to use the iMac as a display in target disk mode from the PC/

The GTX1080 outputs to three DP's(DisplayPorts) and an HDMI. I have tried TDM using a DP to MDP(MiniDisplayPort) cable but have not succeeded in getting past the floating Firewire logo that TDM shows on this iMac build.

I see on Apple's forums it is specifically mentioned that MDP to MDP cable is to be used, and yet, I can find no evidence on the web to suggest that there's any actual difference in the data transmission between DP & MDP.

Is this configuration supported?

Comment: ...floating Firewire logo? That sounds like [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462), not Target Display Mode. I've had success with the same iMac going to an R9 Fury in a Windows build. Also just confirming that it's a 27" iMac?

Comment: Yeah, its an "iMac (27-inch, Late 2009)" as copied from my 'about this Mac'. 

Ok, thank you, yes I was setting it up as Target Disk Mode... doh!
Now, doing the command F2 thing all I get is a black screen. 
I probably should have mentioned that there is no OS on the PC as yet (hence the need to do TDM in the first place), and so the PC is (probably) wanting me to access the BIOS. Would this have any effect on why there's just a black screen?

Comment: For me, the iMacs would automatically switch to video from my tower as soon as it started, as long as the displays started off but not asleep–no command+F2 necessary (that seemed to only be needed with other Macs), and it displayed a BIOS just fine.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try this now.

Comment: OK, well the iMac went black as soon as I booted up the PC, but then cut back to OSx as though Id physically pulled the DP cable. 

FYI 
This is an AMD Threadripper so there is no other video, other than the GTX1080 that I have installed.

Comment: I just tried the 1080 in the other x16 PCI-E slot and its the same situation.

Comment: What brand of cable are you using? Have you confirmed that the PC is posting fine using another monitor?

Comment: I don't actually have another monitor (as yet, though I just ordered one), to test it on. 
I am using a Rosewill 6ft MDP to DP model# RCDC-14026 which supports DP 1.1v and is compatible with DP 1.2v

Comment: Thanks for the help btw. 
The VGA is a Zotac 1080 Mini with an 8 pin power connector, and the PSU is an EVGA G2 supernova 850W, connected with said 8pin. However there is a dual 6pin to 8pin adapter which came with the VGA, Im wondering if I should be using that (2x 6pin) versus using the specified EVGA "VGA" 8pin connector.

Comment: Power delivery sounds fine. I used Startech cables but those ones seem fine. Threadripper has no iGPU and unless you happen to have another GPU on hand seems impossible to test for that. I've used an Asus GTX 1080 before, so it's not a chip thing. TBH without another display this seems like it'll be difficult to debug. Does your motherboard have a Dr. Debug or anything?

Comment: The motherboard is an Asus Zenith Extreme, and by all accounts, it has just about every bell and whistle under the sun... Whether it has Dr.Debug I simply cannot tell you. :/
Apparently, I will get my new monitor Dec 27th, until then I am 'in the dark', literally and figuratively.

Comment: In the [upper left hand corner on the I/O cover there's a little OLED display.](https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/products/QUxljf1tw7eD3ZT4/img/Customization/LiveDash-OLED.png) Does it say anything?

Comment: It says Code A9 BIOS Setup Menu

Comment: Sounds like motherboard (at least it thinks it) is POSTing successfully. Unless your GPU is bad (which I doubt) I'm with you that it's the monitors. There's a small possibility that if you take a video I can spot something that I didn't recognize over text, but besides that, it seems like there's not much to do but wait for a monitor.

Comment: Yeah ok i can shoot a bit of video, cant do it right now though...

Comment: Still waiting for the monitor to arrive...

Comment: :/ hopefully it gets there soon. I'm still around if you want to try more debugging though!

Comment: Monitor finally arrived, I plugged it in and it seems to be working flawlessly.
Even though we never resolved  TDM issue, the fact that I'm here on my new PC typing this is enough of a resolution to end this thread. How do I reward you for your efforts?

Comment: No reward is necessary, but votes are always appreciated! Or really anything tech/gaming related.

Comment: I wonder if you posted an 'answer', would that be more valuable as votes (which Ill give anyway)?

Comment: Also, how do I vote you up!

Comment: I would post an answer if I had been able to solve your issue; if you think any of the other answers I've posted are good though, you're welcome to vote those up! There's a button on the left hand site that you can vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Target Disk mode is booting with a T and the OS not running. You will see a FireWire / USB / Thunderbolt icon in this target mode on supported iMac.

Target Display mode has no icons and needs the Mac OS to be running and is entered with either Command - F2 or Command - Fn - F2 keys.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592

The link above has all the steps to qualify / check your connections and requirements.

Comment: OP already confirmed that even when doing it properly that he's getting a black screen, so something else is up.

Comment: @JMY1000 It's not clear to me that you would see the FireWire icon when entering TDM so I wanted to put up some sort of answer in case it's helpful. Are you saying TDM works without any operational OS running on the Mac end?

Comment: I have already read and re-read that Apple page.

Comment: @bmike Not saying that, just that even when they boot into macOS and do it properly it doesn't work (per their comments.)